# postgresql update true if other table column having value else false

Tags: postgresql

I want to update tableA column as "True" if in tableB column having any value other wise update as false.
The updating process should done for all schema which is having this tables dynamically.
Please help me on this.

update TA set TA.col=true else false (if TB.col having any value)

```
DO $$ 
declare 
  l_rec record; 
  l_schema_name varchar(100); 
  l_sql varchar(100); 
BEGIN 
    for rec in select Table_schema, table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name='table A' and 'table B'
    LOOP
l_schema_name :=rec.Table_schema;
    l_sql := 'update '||l_schema_name||'.TA Set TA.column1= (case when isnull(TB.Column,' ')=' ' then false else true end) From tableA TA left join tableB TB on TA.Col=TB.Col';    
     begin
        execute l_sql;
      end;
    END loop;
END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

i have a solution for the above query.

DO $$
declare
rec record;
l_schema_name varchar(100);
l_sql varchar(1000);
BEGIN
for rec in select Table_schema, table_name from information_schema.tables
where table_name='TA' and table_schema='schema_name'
LOOP
l_schema_name :=rec.Table_schema;
l_sql := 'update '||l_schema_name||'.TableA TA set TA.col=true
where id in (select id from '||l_schema_name||'.Tableb TB)';
begin
execute l_sql;
Raise notice 'Updated for % :',l_schema_name;
end;
END loop;
END;
$$;